# no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator

Tags: c++, class, oop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    class critter{
    public :   // public section
          critter (int hunger =0) ;
        int gethunger() const ;
        void sethunger (int hunger) ;
    private :
         int m_hunger ;

    };

    critter :: critter (int hunger) :
      m_hunger (hunger)
      {
          cout << "new critter has been born" << endl ;
       }
 int critter :: gethunger() const
    {
        return m_hunger ;
    }

    void critter :: sethunger (int hunger)
    {
        if (hunger<0) {
            cout << "you can not set a negative number to hunger" << endl  ;

        }
 else {
    m_hunger=hunger ;
 }
    }
    int main ()
    {

        critter crit(5);
          cout << "calling gethunger()"<<crit.gethunger()<<endl ;

            cout << "calling sethunger ()" << crit.sethunger(-1) << endl ;
             return 0 ;

    }
```

I am getting the following error:
no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::operator<<  >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"calling sethunger ()")) << crit.critter::sethunger(-1)'

in this line:

{cout << "calling sethunger ()" << crit.sethunger(-1) << endl ; }

please tell me why the compiler does not print {you can not set a negative number to hunger}

Comment: sethunger should return a string and no output. Or your main shouldn't try to print this function...

Comment: You can't just replace a `void` return type with `int` and then not return anything. That makes no sense.

Comment: I guess you want to "debug-print" the fact that you are now calling the function and don't need to print any return value (because there isn't any). Either you simply write the call in a second line without any output, or you could hack: `cout << "..." << (crit.sethunger(-1), "") << endl;` -- Explanation: within the parentheses, you first call the function (discarding any return value which here doesn't even exist). Then (after the comma) you provide something which can be printed (empty string).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish by printing the return value of `crit.sethunger(-1)`?  Maybe if you can explain what you're trying to do, it would help someone provide a good answer for you.

Comment: @indiv I guess he thinks that he needs to write it to `cout` in order to see the error messages `sethunger` may generate. But that's a wrong assumption. (But would be the case if it returned the error as a string)

Comment: help me only to get this  code to work  and print the messages

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is right: `void` cannot be printed. What you should do is to call `sethunger()` after you print the message:

```
cout << "calling sethunger ()" << endl;
crit.sethunger(-1);
```

Regarding your update:
*please tell me why the compiler does not print {you can not set a negative number to hunger}*

The messages you write are not printed by the compiler, they are printed by *compiled program*. And as long as your code doesn't compile, there's no program which can write the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "calling sethunger ()" << crit.sethunger(-1) << endl ;
```

The sethunger() member function returns a void. Can't write void on `std::cout`, of course.

Comment: The OP already said this in the question:  "and my guess that the error telling me that the compiler doesn't know how to insert a void to an ostream "

Comment: There's only one person in this entire world who can "get this code to work". That would be you. Only you know what it's supposed to do. The reason for this particular error message was explained to you. std::ostream does not overload on void. Now, you need to figure out what is supposed to happen, instead of that, and change the code accordingly.